# Python app converted as standalone for Windows with Pyinstaller works but takes 23 sec to launch

Tags: python, performance, pyqt5, python-standalone

I made an app with `Python 3.7` and `PyQt5` which works fine on `Windows 10` without problem and launches rapidly (<1 sec) when launched it from the text editor. I then converted it with `PyInstaller` in a standalone app. It works also fine but takes around 25 sec (!) to launch. What the app itself does is:

- it takes a txt file where values with there labels are stored
- it converts the txt file into a csv file (6 columns 128 rows)
- it opens the csv file
- It converts the info of the csv into a panda
- it then evaluates certain values with and construct a report according to the values (ex: if the value of parameter 1 is 50, the corresponding generated text will be "the parameter is high")

As the application is meant to be deployed on computer which don't have python installed and in a workplace environment where this task has to be done many times a day, I imagine the user lambda cursing at the app developer because the app takes 23 seconds to launch

- Is there a way to optimize that time, or is the price to pay for a standalone app written in a interpreted language like python
- Should I forget getting some speed from that solution and re-write the app in C++ . If yes the problem is that I don't know anything about C++ ==> are there some automatic translators?

Many thanks in advance for your insight

Comment: Are you using `--onefile` instead of the default `--onedir`, by any chance?  That requires some of your program's dependencies to be unpacked into a temporary directory every single time it is run, which is the only reason I can think of why it would take so long to launch.

Comment: thank you for your answer @jasonharper. So what I actually did is that I first `cd` the directory where the app is residing and then ran `PyInstaller app.py`. I didn't add whether `--onefile` nor `--onedir`. What do you think I should do?